# Popup window on location.href change

Tags: javascript, dom-events, popupwindow

I have a pop up window being launched as I redirect to social sites for authentication. The callback goes to my server which will return a token in the body of the popup page in JSON.

I want to be able to retrieve the token from the popup window once it complete's it's redirects to a defined URL.

In some sort of pseudo-code I believe it's like this, but I cannot for the life of me track the popup window URL as it's changing.

```
var facebookPopup; 

facebookPopup = window.open(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + "api/identity/login/facebook", "Facebook Login", "width=200, height=200");

onchange(facebookPopup.location.href) {
    if (facebookPopup.location.href === 'destination URL') {
        var token = JSON.parse(facebookPopup.document.body)
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.